# Shisha Ve'esrim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred twenty-six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tehilim (Psalms) 126 is said prior to Birchas HaMazon on Shabbos and Yom Tov, and by the Chasidim also during the week.

7 x Chai 18 = 126

Answer (score 3):

126 is half the number of provinces in the world: *Koresh* should have ruled this many, but ruled 127 instead. (Source: *Midrash Raba*, quoted by *Tora T'mima* to *Ester* 1:1.)

Answer (score 2):

126 are the years of Miriam.

According to [Seder Olam](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34252&st=&pgnum=4), the minimum # of years of the slavery was 86 years, equal to the years of Miriam who was named for the bitterness.  Miriam died during the 40th year in the wilderness.

Comment: And for something seasonal, the # of candles that 21 people will light on the 6th night of Chanuka :)

Answer (score 1):

Both Parshas Lech Lcha and Parshas Reaye have 126 Pesukim